# Nginx caching a full file when range request comes

Tags: caching, nginx

I need to cache full file when range request comes to Nginx. Can i do it?

Example:

We have a binary file. And client asks for Range:bytes=1-100, nginx go to another API download *full* binary file, and give needed range to client, but on the next Range query to the same file, we should be able to take it from cache. So how can i set up nginx to work as follows?

Comment: I have the same issue. If I make a request without the Range header, nginx cache the object and subsequent requests with range header are honored from cache. But if I make only range requests, the object seems to never hit the cache.

Comment: I have just tested it and none of the claims above looks correct to me. Whether Range header present or not nginx pulls the file from the backend in the usual (linear) way: from byte 0 -> to the last byte, and store it in the cache area when the whole file has been retrieved. Meanwhile, the range request is fulfilled right in parallel with pulling from the backend. That is, asking for Range: 20M- of 30M file, you have to wait untill first 20M of the file have been downloaded, and then you start getting your bytes in parallel with pulling from the backend...